# Dart Flutter - How do I combine & convert separated date & time into one DateTime object

Tags: flutter, dart

```
String oldDateStr = "2022-08-1";
String oldTimeStr = "03:10 pm";
DateTime? newDateTime;  //2022-08-01 13:10  (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm) <----- TARGET

final olddateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-d");
final newdateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
final oldtimeFormat = DateFormat("hh:mm a");
final timeFormatter = DateFormat("HH:mm");

DateTime oldTime12 = oldtimeFormat.parse(oldTimeStr.toUpperCase());
DateTime newTime24 = DateTime.parse(timeFormatter.format(oldTime12)); //This line is culprit  in print() debug
DateTime oldDate = olddateFormat.parse(oldDateStr);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.parse(newdateFormat.format(oldDate));
```

I tried & combined various answers from SO posts but couldn't figure this out. So I'm posting the question by helplessness.

Comment: Combine the two strings before parsing it into a `DateTime` using a `DateFormat` that takes this combined `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted format is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa`. am/pm marker assumes capital letters e.g PM.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String oldDateStr = "2022-08-1";
  String oldTimeStr = "03:10 pm";

  final result = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa").parse(
    '$oldDateStr $oldTimeStr'.replaceAll('pm', 'PM').replaceAll('am', 'AM'),
  );
  print(result); // 2022-08-01 15:10:00.000
}
```

See [DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get formatted date like this,  make a function if you are using it frequently.

```
  String oldDateStr = "2022-08-01";
  String oldTimeStr = "03:10 pm";
  DateTime? newDateTime;
  String newDate = (oldDateStr + " "+oldTimeStr.substring(0, 5) + ":00.000");
  DateFormat formatter = DateFormat ('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
  DateTime nt = DateTime.parse(newDate);
  print(formatter.format(nt));
```

Answer (score 0):

use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to combine date and time and convert your datetime format to DateTime

```
String oldDateStr = "2022-08-1";
String oldTimeStr = "03:10 pm";

final String dateTimeString = oldDateStr+ " " + oldTimeStr;
final DateFormat format = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
print (format.parse(dateTimeString));
```